# Where is the value of a variable stored in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I learned that in Ruby an object is just a bunch of instance variables and a link to a class (Metaprogramming Ruby 2, The Pragmatic Bookshelf).

When I create a variable, I make an instance of a class and assign it a value. Am I wrong in thinking that this value is stored in the object as an instance variable? When I call instance_variables, none show up. Example:

```
str = "hello"          # => "hello"
str.class              # => String
str.instance_variables # => []
```

If `str` is an object and it equals `"hello"`, where is `"hello"` stored?

Comment: Native classes are ... special.

Comment: What would you expect in such an instance variable if it did exist anyways?

Comment: @JanDvorak maybe something like `@value = "hello"`? I don't know. I know a lot of the native Ruby classes are written in C so maybe they are exceptions. Something just isn't clicking in my brain.

Comment: Such `@value` is, within the string context, better known as `self`

Answer (score 2):

A variable is not an object.  It is a programming language construct that provides a way to *refer to* an object in your source code.

For example, in the code below, the initalization of `b` does *not* create a new object, only a new variable that refers to an object:

```
2.3.0 :012 > a = 'a string'
 => "a string"
2.3.0 :013 > b = a
 => "a string"
```

Comment: But what about `a`? You created an object when you created `a` and you assigned it a value. Where does that value live if not in the object? And how should I imagine it living in the object? @JanDvorak said something interesting about the value being `self` in the context of the object. Can you confirm that and/or expand upon it?

Comment: No, there was no object created when I created `a`, only when I specified the string literal `'a string'`.  The assignments to `a` and `b` did not result in the creation of any new objects.  The value is the object, and vice versa; the variable is just a construct with which to refer to the value or object.  Regarding @JanDvorak's comment, I don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the Ruby classes are, as Jan pointed out, special. What this means is the internals are implemented in C, not Ruby, so they're invisible to the usual reflection tools.

You can have a look inside the [Ruby source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby) to see how this plays out.

In the case of string there's no instance variable that stores the string, the string itself *is* where it's stored.

Answer (score 0):

Local variable `str` that you made is not an instance variable.

If you create an instance variable, then that is stored in the object. However, it does not make sense to call `instance_variables` on the variable itself. You should call it on the object on which it is stored (in this case the implicit main context).

```
@str = "hello"
instance_variables # => [:@str]
```

Comment: I hope whomever downvoted this hasn't done so because of their lack of comprehension skill. By "store" or "location", the OP doesn't mean the physical memory location, but is mentioning it in a more abstract sense in relation to OOP.